# Best practise to search in MySQL result

Tags: php, mysql, loops

Good day everyone. I am trying to find out what is the best way to search inside a select statement. I currently have the following select statement:

```
$sql_grn = "SELECT fl_voucher_no, fl_voucher_grn, tb_customers.fl_cust_name "
                    . "FROM tb_vouchers "
                    . "Join tb_customers on tb_vouchers.fl_voucher_customer = tb_customers.fl_cust_accno "
                    . "WHERE fl_voucher_grn LIKE  '%$grn%'";
```

This returns all the voucher numbers linked to the grn searched. They now want to have displayed the vouchers's status which is in another table.

I was thinking of putting another mysql query in the while loop:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {   
                /*another mysql query here finding the status based on the voucher number*/
                echo "<tr><td>$row[fl_voucher_no]</td><td>$row[fl_voucher_grn]</td><td>$row[fl_cust_name]</td></tr>";
            }
```

Is this the right way to do it or is there better way that is easier on the database or server?

Thank you so much

Comment: Share details of the table containing vouchers's status.

Comment: Best would be to make MySQL do the work for you and only return what you need. if you are returning data that's not being used it's a waste

Comment: Thanks Guys, Dave would that mean doing a nested select statement?

Comment: I would prolly throw in another join before nested select statements, depends on your table schemata and relations

Comment: The voucher status table can have multiple entries with the same voucher number. since it has to log everytime the voucher was sent for verification...so there can be voucher001, rejected and a data. Then later voucher001, accepted and then a date. would a join still work in this case?

Comment: Thanks guys. I used the following code in mysql query and so far it is working: SELECT fl_voucher_no, fl_voucher_grn, tb_customers.fl_cust_name, tb_accepted.fl_claim_status, tb_accepted.fl_date FROM tb_vouchers 

Join tb_customers on tb_vouchers.fl_voucher_customer = tb_customers.fl_cust_accno 

Join tb_accepted ON tb_vouchers.fl_voucher_no = tb_accepted.fl_voucher

WHERE fl_voucher_grn LIKE '%123%'

Order by tb_accepted.fl_date desc

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I used the join suggestion as follows:

```
SELECT fl_voucher_no, fl_voucher_grn, tb_customers.fl_cust_name, tb_accepted.fl_claim_status, tb_accepted.fl_date, tb_accepted.fl_rate FROM tb_vouchers
                        Join tb_customers on tb_vouchers.fl_voucher_customer = tb_customers.fl_cust_accno 
                        left Join tb_accepted ON tb_vouchers.fl_voucher_no = tb_accepted.fl_voucher
                        WHERE fl_voucher_grn LIKE '%$grn%'
                        Order by tb_accepted.fl_date desc"
```

Which then places the most recent interaction of that voucher at the top.
Thank for all the help!